# Creating a plotly vrect over all axis of a matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly

I have a complete matplotlib figure with multiple subplots and I want to add a vertical span in a specific range to all of the subplots. The remaining plot is then converted to plotly.

If I try running xvspan over each individual subplot when creating the matplotlib figure, the vertical spans do not make it into the plotly figure.

If I try converting the figure into plotly first and then adding a vrect, this vrect only seems to work for the first subplot. I have tried using `row = "all"` to no avail.

Any other ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you are missing a requirement to get an answer. I think you need to provide sample data or current created code and output diagrams.

Comment: If you can add some code for more detail, I'd love to help. Not sure what you mean by "vertical span". Do you mean a highlighted region on an axis, or a rectangle or line of some kind within the plot area?

Comment: show your demo data and sample plot